# Update query showing old data after submitting

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name' WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<h4>Your information has been updated</h4><br />";
```

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <p>
        <label for='name'>Name</label><br /><br />
        <input class="input-text required" name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $row[name]; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" /></p>
</form>
```

After clicking Update, it updates the information in the database, but the `<?php echo $row['name']; ?>` still shows the old value. Only after refreshing the page does it show the updated information. I could have it refresh the page after updating by echoing meta refresh but I want it to still show the echo saying "Your info has been updated" which doesn't happen if I set it to refresh. Is there any solution?

Comment: Did you perhaps fetch `$row` *before* the `UPDATE` query? Also, please use parametrized queries instead of string interpolation — I hope `$name` and `$email` have, at the very least, been escaped. Finally, why not use `$name`?

Comment: Yes I did fetch it before `UPDATE`. I did escape all the variables...I didn't show all that code here. What are parametrized queries?

Comment: Did a search and found out about parametrized queries using PDO. Will do that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to requery the database to repopulate `$row` or explicitly set the `$row` variable to your values (I would recommend repopulating it, just to be safe).

Or `echo $name`, instead of `$row[name]`

Answer (score 1):

A update of the database is not a new select of the data.

You have 2 options:

- after the update, do a new select of the data
- instead of writing the row back to the form, write the posted value back

Comment: Thank you I decided to do a new select